# <NuxtLink> in Nuxt 3 only show the page's content after refreshing

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-link, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use `<NuxtLink>` to redirect in Nuxt 3.

However, my page won't show after the URL change.
That means, after clicking the link, the URL changes to whatever is stated in the to="", but the content doesn't show unless I refresh the page.
Wonder what did I do wrong.

Here is my Routing code

```
 <template>
      <div class="top-nav-tab">
        <NuxtLink to="/foundations"><h3>Foundations</h3></NuxtLink>
     </div>
   </template>
```

Here is my page code

```
<template>
  <h2>Foundation page</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show us your routes?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with that code, are you sure you have all the dependencies up to date?

Comment: It's related to `useAsyncData` if you're using it in a lazy mode, something doesn't fetch from API correctly, thus it won't show anything

Comment: I wonder if it is fixed? 

Comment: Check your console maybe you have error in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NuxtLink, Why not use another implementation like: `navigateTo()` as Nuxtlink creates a lazyloaded component by default? So in this use case just do something like

```html
<h3 @click="navigateTo('/foundation')"> Foundation </h3>
```

This would perform the action; and its preferred way by the documentation

Comment: Lazy loaded component? You rather mean prefetching no? Also, a11y semantics are important: a link should move you to a place, not a button or even an `h3`.

Answer (score -5):

I've got the same issue so I use native javascript instead.

```js
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "/";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("/");
```

Comment: Nope, please DO NOT use this because you will nuke your SPA. There is no point into doing that. Totally counter-productive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).